# importing jdl file creates a lot of conflicts

Tags: jhipster, jdl, jhipster-blueprint

I am new to jhipster and was trying out the import-jdl feature.

I created a sample application which uses mysql as database and angular for front end. i used the following configuration to create it. Please not that i didnt choose any cache option.

```
? Which *type* of application would you like to create? Monolithic application (recommended for simple projects)
? What is the base name of your application? jdlimporttest
? Do you want to make it reactive with Spring WebFlux? No
? What is your default Java package name? com.mycompany.myapp
? Which *type* of authentication would you like to use? JWT authentication (stateless, with a token)
? Which *type* of database would you like to use? SQL (H2, PostgreSQL, MySQL, MariaDB, Oracle, MSSQL)
? Which *production* database would you like to use? MySQL
? Which *development* database would you like to use? MySQL
? Which cache do you want to use? (Spring cache abstraction) No cache - Warning, when using an SQL database, this will
disable the Hibernate 2nd level cache!
? Would you like to use Maven or Gradle for building the backend? Maven
? Do you want to use the JHipster Registry to configure, monitor and scale your application? No
? Which other technologies would you like to use?
? Which *Framework* would you like to use for the client? Angular
? Do you want to generate the admin UI? Yes
? Would you like to use a Bootswatch theme (https://bootswatch.com/)? Default JHipster
? Would you like to enable internationalization support? No
? Please choose the native language of the application English
? Besides JUnit and Jest, which testing frameworks would you like to use?
? Would you like to install other generators from the JHipster Marketplace? No
```

I tried to import a dummy jdl file with minimum configurations. which is given below,

```
application {
  config {
    baseName jdlimporttest,
    applicationType monolith,
    packageName com.mycompany.myapp,
    authenticationType jwt,
    prodDatabaseType mysql,
    clientFramework angular
  }
  entities *
}

entity Product {
productId String
productName String
description String
price Long
specifications String
}

entity Inventory {
id String
    inStock Integer
    purchased Integer
}
```

When i tried to import it, i got conflicts in large number of files. I can understand why there was conflicts in ui files. But i am not sure why the import feature, tried to change my dev db to h2 and enable the ehchache, which i disabled while creating the sample application.

I got conflicts in the below files and all the default entities and some ui files,

```
package.json                                                        
src\main\resources\config\liquibase\master.xml                  
pom.xml                                                         
src\main\resources\logback-spring.xml                               
src\main\resources\config\application.yml                           
src\main\resources\config\application-dev.yml                       
src\main\resources\config\application-prod.yml                  
src\main\java\com\mycompany\myapp\config\WebConfigurer.java     
src\main\java\com\mycompany\myapp\config\SecurityConfiguration.java
DatabaseConfiguration.java                                      
ExceptionTranslator.java                                            
logback.xml
```

I am using the jhipster 7.9.3 version.

Can anyone please explain why this is happening and is there any configuration to make use the import-jdl feature doesnt change the db and cache configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `application` block at the top since you already created your application. If you remove it, everything should work much smoother.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the application definition to match, first export the existing definition:

`jhipster export-jdl`

Then add your new entities to the generated file.